# How to install python module as a command line application under windows?

Tags: python

I need to install a python module in the site packages that also will be used as a command line application. Suppose I have a module like:

app.py

```
def main():
  print 'Dummy message'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

setup.py

```
 import distutils

 try:
   from setuptools import setup
 except ImportError:
   from distutils.core import setup

 if __name__ == '__main__':

    setup(name = 'dummy',
            version = '1.0',
            packages = ['dummy'],
    )
```

Creating the dist by:

```
    setup.py sdist
```

Install:

```
    setup.py install
```

And now I would like to use it as a command line application by opening the command window and typing just:  dummy

Is it possible to create such application under windows without to carry out registering system pat variables and so on ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following in `dummy.cmd`:

```
python.exe -m dummy
```

Or is it `dummy.app`...

Oh well, it's one of those.

Comment: Wow, and thats all?
Shell I include this to the package distribution as well?

Comment: I personally wouldn't bother, because it's just so not difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the options in setup.py to declare command line scripts. Please refer to [this article](http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2008/01/setuptools_tip_script_creation.html). On Windows, the script will be created in "C:\Python26\Scripts" (if you didn't change the path) - lots of tools store their scripts there (e.g. "easy_install", "hg", ...).